# How to find current row in jQgrid?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I have a list of users in my jQgrid table and now I want to make subgrid which will list all projects for a selected user.

Of course, they have has_many and belongs_to relationship.

Now my code looks like this

```
jQuery("#datatable").jqGrid({
              url: "/user/details",
              serializeGridData: function(data) {
                  var Data = jQuery.extend(data, {
                      _search: "true",
                      date_from: function() { return jQuery("#date_from").val(); },
                      date_to: function() { return jQuery("#date_to").val();
                  });
                  return jQuery.param(Data);
              },
              ajaxGridOptions: {async: true},
              ajaxCellOptions: {async: true},
              ajaxRowOptions: {async: true},
              mtype: "POST",
              datatype: "local",
              overlay: "false",
              jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
              loadonce: false,
              pager: '#nav_grid',
              rowEdit: true,
              colNames:['id','Name','Surname', 'Age', 'Company'],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'id',key:true,hidden:true,width:0,index:'id', sorttype:"int", editable: false, align:'left',search:true},
                  {name:'name',width:175,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true},
                  {name:'surname',fixed:true,width:250,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true},
                  {name:'age',width:0,index:'item_code', sorttype:"int", editable: false, align:'left',search:true},
                  {name:'company',width:300,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true},
                  {name:'company',width:100,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true,formatter:'currency'}
              ],

                  jQuery('[id^="gs"]').attr("placeholder", "Search...");
              },
              rownum:500,
              rowNum:500,
              rowList:[500, 1000],
              shrinktofit: true,
              forcefit: false,
              autowidth:true,
              sortname: 'projects',
              sortorder: "desc",
              height: "380",
              ignoreCase: true,
              viewrecords: true,
              caption:"",
              subGrid: true,
              subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {

                  var user_id = jQuery('#data_table').getRowData(row_id)['user_id']
                  var subgrid_table_id;
                  subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
                  jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+ "p_"+subgrid_table_id +"' class='scroll'></div>");
                  jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                      url:"/user/project_details",
                      datatype: "json",
                      jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
                      postData:  data,
                      colNames: ['id','Category','Supplier', 'Item Code', 'Name', 'Price', '#','Unit', 'Total Cost (no tax)', 'Total Tax', 'Charges', 'Credits', 'Grand Total'],
                      colModel: [
                          {name:'project_id',key:true,hidden:true,width:0,index:'id', sorttype:"int", editable: false, align:'left',search:true},
                          {name:'project_name',width:175,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true},
                          {name:'email',fixed:true,width:250,sortable:true, align:'left',search:true},
                          {name:'user_id',width:0,index:'item_code', sorttype:"int", editable: false, align:'left',search:true},

                      ],
                      height: '100%',
                      sortname: 'num',
                      sortorder: "asc",
                      shrinktofit: true,
                      forcefit: false,
                      autowidth:true,
                      rownum:500,
                      rowNum:500,
                      loadonce:true,
                      rowList:[500,1000],
                      viewrecords: true,
                      pager:"p_"+subgrid_table_id
                  });
```

The question is how to find current_row(selected row) and then list all projects which beongs to selected user.

In User controller(this is projects which should be listed in subgrid)

```
def index
 @projects = Project.joins(:user).where(:projects => {project_id: selected_user.id(?))
end
```

I tried something like this but I don't know how to name selected_user.id, is there any method for this?

Or if this is not good at all, how would you recommend to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem you will need to set selectOnExpand options in subGridOptions in order to get current selected row. See [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/subgrid/#properties)

```
subGrid: true,
subGridOptions : {
    selectOnExpand : true
}
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
...
}
```